# DataGridCell и цвет селекта + AlternationIndex

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Есть стиль

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Name="PART_Border2"
                BorderThickness="0" 
                Background="Transparent">
          <Border Name="PART_Border1"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" 
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" 
                  Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
          </Border>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Border2" Property="Background" Value="#20000000" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
      <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="White"/>             
    </Trigger>                                                               
    <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="#ffeaecef"/>         
    </Trigger>                                                               
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="#ffdee7f7"/>         
    </Trigger>                                                                      
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Суть в том, что я хочу выбирать цвет PART_Border2 в зависимости от IsSelected ячейки. И цвет этот делать полупрозрачным, чтобы прослеживался AlternationIndex строки. Но ячейка устанавливает свой (синий) Background в PART_Border1.Background, а вот как это игнорировать я не знаю. Или может есть другие методы.

Comment: Попробуйте для стиля `DataGridCell` добавить `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />` перед заданием шаблона.

Comment: Я походу понял свою ошибку. В стиле DataGridRow я устанавливаю Background ячейки. А надо строки. Вроде у меня получилось создать стиль. Потестю ещё. Если все будет норм и никто не ответит на мой вопрос напишу свой ответ.

Comment: элемент DataGrid является сложным и у него есть собственная кисть для рисования BorderBrush, которая используется на выбранных элементах. Что бы избавиться от этого эффекта, Вам надо ее переопределить, к примеру сделать прозрачный и определить дочерние цвета для row и cell. Вполне возможно, надо определить кисть только для row и cell и можно не трогать общую кисть.

Comment: Посмотрите, как это делается: [пример один](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539909/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-style), [пример два](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223280/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-a-selected-row-in-datagrid), [пример три](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998112/datagrids-selected-row-color-when-inactive), [пример 4 MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9e28b36-28fe-47b3-adae-504305bb67de/how-to-change-wpf-datagrid-selecteditem-background-color?forum=wpf)

Comment: @Alex Krass я эти посты смотрел, если вы прочтете про AlternationIndex поймёте почему эти примеры мне не подходят

Comment: Хорошо, я посмотрю, что там с этим свойством. Если что, пишите свой ответ, мне тоже интересно, т.к. периодически мучаюсь с этим контролом.

Comment: @Alex Krass я токачто нашел косяк в моем ответе, пока его постить не буду. Мой стиль перекрывает все фоны в некоторых ячейках, которые я задаю явно... Исправлю, потестю, напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока итог каков

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
      <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="White"/>             
    </Trigger>                                                               
    <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="#ffeaecef"/>         
    </Trigger>                                                               
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="#ffdee7f7"/>         
    </Trigger>                                                                     
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Name="PART_Border" BorderThickness="0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}">
           <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Border.Background" Value="#60003489" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```